# Jquery datatable add extra row after loading initial datasource from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I initially loaded data using ajax

```
function loadskills(userid){
    var skilltable=$('#skills_table').DataTable(
    {

        "ajax":{
            "url":"getskills/"+userid
        },

        "columns" : [
            { "data" : "id" },
            { "data" : "skill" }
        ],
        'columnDefs': [{
            'targets': 0,
            'searchable':false,
            'orderable':false,
            'className': 'dt-body-center text-center ',
            'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                console.log("data : "+data);
                return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' 
                   + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '" checked>';
            }
        }],
        "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex){
           // console.log('createdRow row '+row);
            $(row).attr("id", "tblRow_" + data.id);
        },
        searching: true,
        "order": [],
        bFilter: false,
        dom: "lirpt",

    }
    );
```

The data loads fine is the table. But after i want to add a couple rows in json object. example

```
var data = [
{
    "id":1,
    "skill":"LanTest101"

}];
```

and "append" it to the already loaded data.
i tried using tablename.row.add() but i get an error

```
skilltable.row.add(data).draw();
```

which "requested unknown parameter 'skill' for row 0"

after extending the object here are the changes

```
"ajax":{
            "url":"getskills/"+userid,
            "dataSrc":function(data){
                //console.log("user skills "+JSON.stringify(data));
                 $.extend(data, skills);
                 //console.log("after merging "+JSON.stringify(data));
                 return $.extend(data, skills);
            }
        },
```

Comment: edited with comments

Comment: Why not [extending](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) your data object before rendering?

Comment: not a bad idea ShaharGalukman. i will do that and give feedback

Comment: @ShaharGalukman after extending the data which works . datatable is not recognizing the new data. i'm editing the question to include the code changes

Comment: Just ensure the data you add is with the same structure of the data received.
If issue persist provide the actual error for better understanding of what's wrong..